# Задача из Проекта Эйлера: вроде решил, ответ по примеру верный(если брать 4 последовательных числа), а вот если взять 13 чисел, то неверное

Tags: java

Условие:

Наибольшее произведение четырех последовательных цифр в нижеприведенном 1000-значном числе равно 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934 96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843 85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511 12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557 66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113 62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749 30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866 70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776 65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243 52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397 53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482 83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474 82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881 16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586 17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042 24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408 07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188 84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606 05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725 71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

Найдите наибольшее произведение тринадцати последовательных цифр в данном числе.

Повторюсь, если взять 4 числа, как в примере, то ответ сходится, но если взять 13 чисел, то выдает ответ: 2091059712, а верный: 23514624000; Прошу помощи( Вот мой код:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934" +
            "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843" +
            "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511" +
            "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557" +
            "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113" +
            "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749" +
            "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866" +
            "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776" +
            "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243" +
            "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397" +
            "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482" +
            "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474" +
            "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881" +
            "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586" +
            "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042" +
            "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408" +
            "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188" +
            "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606" +
            "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725" +
            "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

    long max = 0;
    int  j, number, x, y, search = 12;
    int SIZE = s.length();
    String[] arr = new String[SIZE];

    char c;
    String value;

    for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ ) {
        c = s.charAt(i);
        arr[i] = String.valueOf(c);
    }

    for ( int i = search; i < SIZE; i++ ) {
        j = search; x = 1;

        while ( j != -1 ) {
            value = arr[i - j];
            number = Integer.parseInt(value);
            x *= number;

            j--;
        }

        y = x;

        if (y > max ) max = y;
    }

    System.out.println(max);
}
}
```

Если хотите проверить первый пример, то вам надо изменить переменную search на 3

Comment: Произведение тринадцати девяток не по мещается в `int`. У вас переполнения. Верный ответ *23514624000* тоже больше чем может вместить  `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Для решения проблемы с вычислениями достаточно определить, что переменные для накопления произведения `x`, `y` имеют тип `long`, которого хватит для хранения максимально возможного числа **9<sup>13</sup>**, как указал в комментарии @Stanislav Volodarskiy:

```java
long max = 0, x, y;
//...
```

В ответе будет выведено искомое число: `23514624000`

Но и 64-битного типа `long` может оказаться недостаточно Для поиска максимального произведения более длинных последовательностей, *не содержащих нулей*, тогда может потребоваться тип [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Однако не совсем понятно, для чего потребовалось создавать отдельный массив *строк* размером с исходную строку только для того, чтобы записать туда цифры в виде строк.
Для получения численного значения цифрового символа достаточно использовать метод [`Character::getNumericValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-char-).
Также можно было бы немного оптимизировать код, например, при обнаружении 0 произведение станет равным 0, поэтому можно передвинуть указатель на следующее за нулём число:

```java
// String s = "7316717653133062491...";
long max = 0;
int search = 13; // корректная длина последовательности

for (int i = search, size = s.length(); i <= size; i++) {
    long p = 1L;
    int j = i - search;
    while (p > 0 && j < i) {
        p *= Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(j++));
    }
    
    if (p == 0) i = search + j - 1; // переход на следующий символ после нуля
    else if (p > max) max = p;
}
System.out.println(max); // 23514624000
```